# go ahead vs go forward vs go on

Tags: differences

Can someone clarify differences between these three?

Sometime it is confusing which one to use

**Thanks!**

Comment: You can google all of those, and they give you a different answer for all of them. Either you have to clarify what the confusion is, or the dictionary should suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- go ahead - *start something/continue*

> I decided to go ahead with the plan.

- go forward - *also start something*, or *walking to something*, or *continue*

> George decided to go forward with his idea.

..

> George went forward to bow at the king's feet.

- go on - *continue*

> George decided to go on doing it the way he had before.